# Global variable is None instead of instance - Python

Tags: python, global-variables, nonetype

I'm dealing with global variables in Python. The code should work fine, but there is a problem. I have to use global variable for instance of class `Back`. When I run the application it says that back is None which should be not true because the second line in `setup()` function - `'back = Back.Back()'`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template


import Search
import Back

app = Flask(__name__)
global back
back = None

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

def setup():
    global back
    back = Back.Back()

def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)  

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    from time import time

    pattern = request.form['text']

    startTime = time()

    pattern=pattern.lower()

    arr = []

    if len(pattern)<1:
        arr.append('Incorrect input')

        currentTime = time()-startTime

        return render_template('my-form.html', arr=arr, time=currentTime)


    arr = []

    search = Search.Search(pattern,back)
    results =  search.getResults()

    ..................

    return render_template('my-form.html', arr=arr, time=currentTime, pattern=pattern)


app.debug=True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    app.run()
```

Why is the back variable None instead of instance of Back class? Thanks

Comment: And how are you running your server? With just the Flask built-in development server?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I put all files on my directory in https://www.pythonanywhere.com/. I think that on my computer it works... I have a Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The Flask development server runs your module *twice*. Once to run the server itself, and another time in a child process so it can reload your whole script each time you make a change to it. It is that *second* process that won't run the `__main__` guarded code and the global is left as `None`.

You'll get the same problem if you used another WSGI server; it'd import your file as a module, not as the initial script and the `__main__` guard is not executed.

Use a [`@app.before_first_request` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) instead; it is guaranteed to be executed when the very first request is handled *for this process*. This also keeps your global working if you moved to a proper WSGI container that used multiple child processes to scale your site:

```
@app.before_first_request
def setup():
    global back
    back = Back.Back()
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I have still the same problem. I put this annotation  there.

Comment: @Milan: Are you certain that you are now running the new version using `before_first_request`? Did you try using logging to track what is going on? Include [`os.getpid()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getpid) results in those logging entries to track what process is running what.

Comment: Yes I'm. Finally I solved it using singleton. Just make a singleton class of Back and then everywhere where is back variable I put Back.Back().